# Query very slow with bit fields and full text search

Tags: sql-server

I have a strange problem, if I execute the following query, Sql Server (2008 and 2016) needs about 35 seconds to complete.

```
SELECT DISTINCT F.FilterTitle, F.FilterSlug, F.FilterOrderList, F.FilterType

FROM products p
JOIN products_translations pt ON pt.ProductId = p.Id AND pt.Culture = 'it'
JOIN facets F ON F.ProductId = p.Id AND F.Culture = 'it' AND F.FilterType = 2
JOIN products_categories pc ON pc.productId = p.id
JOIN categories C ON pc.CategoryId = C.Id
JOIN categories_slugs cps ON cps.CategoryId = C.ParentCategoryId AND cps.Culture = 'it'
JOIN categories_slugs cs ON cs.CategoryId = C.Id AND cs.Culture = 'it'

WHERE cps.value = 'string1' AND cs.value = 'string2'
AND CONTAINS(pt.DescriptionForSearch, '"value*"', LANGUAGE 1040) --this is a full text
AND p.Visible = 1 AND p.Payments = 0 --both are bit fields

ORDER BY F.FilterType, F.FilterOrderList, F.FilterTitle;
```

If I comment the line

```
and p.Visible = 1 and p.Payments = 0
```

the query needs just a couple of ms. The same if I remove the line

```
and contains(pt.DescriptionForSearch, '"value*"' , language 1040)
```

and leave the other statement intact. I also created two indexes for both the bit fields without changes.

Can someone shed some light on why this is happening?

**UPDATE**

[At this link](https://file.town/download/ev3zcxlwucif5qrbbpx40dum9) the two execution plans that I forgot to include.

Comment: Did you do any profiling?  If so, could you share it with us?  The `p` and `pt` are just tables? (perhaps something else like views?)

Comment: There is no magic wand. You look at the execution plan. Offhand, without the bit columns in the where clause I would guess that the optimizer completely ignores the products table since the other tables contain the same columns. The resultset contains no columns from products and contains DISTINCT - which makes me suspicious of the logic. I'll also guess that the vast majority of rows in P have visible set to 1 - resulting in a table scan. But that is all guessing.

Comment: You are right I forgot the execution plan, sorry about that. I tried both distinct or group by to experiment, but nothing changed.